# Cannot Redirect to the correct page using PHP session

Tags: php, session

In my application I have 4 roles. As per the roles, Users can view their access different pages. Currently I am maintaining 2 different sessions. `$_SESSION['user_id']` and `$_SESSION['role_id']`.

My problem is, suppose we say the `role_id =1` is `Admin`, `role_id=2` is `Doctor`. If I logout from this session as `Admin` and logging as a `Doctor` to the site. Then I have click back button in `web browser`, it will redirect to the `Admin page`. I don't want to `redirect` to the `Admin page`, just I want to remain in the same page.

Here I have used this codes to redirect but no working.

```
 //  redirect to main page according to the user role 
     if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['role_id'] == 1){//admin
        header("location: index-2.php");
        exit;
     }

     if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['role_id'] == 2){ // doctor
        header("location: index.php");
        exit;
     }
     
     if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['role_id'] == 3){// lab
        header("location: index-lab.php");
        exit;
     }

     if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['role_id'] == 4){// recep
        header("location: index-recep.php");
        exit;
     }
```

I don't know where I went wrong. Could someone help me. Any help may highly appreciated.

Comment: *"Then I have click back button in web browser, it will redirect to the Admin page"* the cache is loaded when you click back, it's not a php issue, that's how browsers work

Comment: @Cid `$_SESSION['user_id']` is still remaining. That is why.

Comment: @Cid `$_SESSION['user_id'] ` is same for every page, `$_SESSION['role_id']` is different for roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Cid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8398549/cid) mentioned, the cache is loaded when you click the back button. This isn't something I've really tried, but you could try setting cache settings for your application to prevent the pages from being cached. See [How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)